# Не работают скрипты в magnific popup ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На странице много модалок и я решил использовать magnific popup  вызывать их через ajax.

```
<a href="path-to-file.html" class="ajax-popup-link">Show inline popup</a>

$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
   type: 'ajax'
});
```

Проблема в том что в этих попапах не работают скрипты, например не инициализируется select2 библиотека или даже обычный клик по кнопке чтоб добавить ей класс, как решить проблему?
Пытался через делегацию, но без результата

```
$(document).magnificPopup({
    delegate: '.ajax-popup-link',
    type: 'ajax',
});
```